# How to avoid floating point overflows in PostgreSQL?

Tags: sql, postgresql, floating-point

In PostgreSQL, when running a computation like this:

```sql
select 1E300::float * 1E300::float
```

I'd like to receive an `'Infinity'::float` value, similar to when I do that in Java or CockroachDB. Instead, I'm getting:

> SQL Error [22003]: ERROR: value out of range: overflow

[SQLFiddle here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_14&fiddle=7ac5dea74c318d9fcbf8f6fd63b277e3). How can I do this?

Answer (score 1):

if you can encapsulate your `select` statement in a plpgsql function then you can manage the error like this :

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION multiply_by_float(a float, b float)
RETURNS float LANGUAGE plpgsql IMMUTABLE AS
$$
DECLARE 
  res float ;
BEGIN
  SELECT a * b INTO res ;
  RETURN res ;
EXCEPTION WHEN OTHERS THEN
  CASE
    WHEN (a > 0 and b < 0) or (a < 0 and b > 0)
    THEN RETURN '-Infinity';
    ELSE RETURN 'Infinity' ;
  END CASE ;
END ;
$$ ;
```

Then `SELECT multiply_by_float(1E300::float, 1E300::float)` returns `Infinity`.

Comment: You can use the above function in a select as well `select multiply_by_float(1E300::float, 1E300::float)`

Answer (score 0):

you can use numeric and decimal types [PG doc](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/13/datatype-numeric.html)

```
select 1E300::decimal * 1E300::decimal;
```

result

```
select 1E300::decimal * 1E300::decimal;
                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                         ?column?                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                       
---------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
 1000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000
```

Comment: That just delays the inevitable. Try this: `select 1E300::decimal ^ 1000`